# Add data to promise return

Tags: return, promise, bluebird

For example:

```
    return getPackages()
        .map(function(package){
            console.log(package.name);
            return latestAsync(package.name)
        })
        .each(function(version) {
            //I want package to make it so it will be in this scope too
            console.log(package.name, package.version, version) 
        });
```

I want to send `package` forward to the next each/then at the time the promise is    fulfilled.
How is that possible?

I am using bluebird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a composite value with it, using [`Promise.props`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#props---promise):

```
return getPackages()
    .map(function(package){
        console.log(package.name);
        return Promise.props({version: latestAsync(package.name), package: package });
    })
    .each(function(r) {
        //I want package to make it so it will be in this scope too
        console.log(r.package.name, r.package.version, r.version) 
    });
```

Alternative solutions are:

- Using [`.bind` to set a scope explicitly](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise) and relying on indices.
- Nest one level and use closure scoping (put a `.then` on the `latestAsync`).
- Using a similar approach with an array instead of an object with [`Promise.all`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise).